# How to let PostgreSQL accept text as enum value

Tags: postgresql, types, npgsql

When I have a table with an `ENUM` column, and I insert like this:

```
UPDATE table SET enum_col = 'enum_value';
```

this works fine, but when explicitly casting it, I get an error:

```
UPDATE table SET enum_col = 'enum_value'::text;

ERROR:  column "enum_col" is of type some_enum_type but expression is of type text
LINE 1: UPDATE table SET enum_col = 'enum_value'::text;
                                    ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I understand the error, but is there some setting I can use, so PostgreSQL will accept it anyway?

(Some extra background, I am using Npgsql to update data in a database, and even though I do not put the `::text` in my query, I do get this error. It looks like Npgsql adds the explicit value types when using parametrised queries.)

Comment: Does this [Enums](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html) help?

Comment: To get this `UPDATE table SET enum_col = 'enum_value'::text;` to work do instead: `UPDATE table SET enum_col = 'enum_value'::some_enum_type;`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this certainly helps, but unfortunately at this point I cannot touch the C# code, plus it is some generic code.

Comment: If possible you should prefer using tables with foreign keys instead of enum types which are mostly difficult to handle (update, delete values, inserting with frameworks, ...)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you are out of luck. The type check is done early in the process so a `BEFORE` trigger does not work. A  custom `CAST` is not going to work as the source(text) is to generic.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver looks like it yes. I'll update my parameters to have the correct type. So I'll have to touch the code anyway.

Comment: @S-Man yes. But you know. Legacy code ;-)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a cast from `text` to your enum type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_enum AS ENUM ('one', 'two', 'three');

CREATE CAST (text AS my_enum) WITH INOUT AS ASSIGNMENT;

CREATE TABLE mytab (enum_col my_enum);

INSERT INTO mytab VALUES ('one'::text);
INSERT 0 1
```

You need to be a superuser to create a type cast.